# How to show a date in expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I am trying to to show a date in an expression but getting a error. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<span>{{new Date(year, month, day) | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</span>
```

I get an error when running this code

Comment: it is on the angularjs scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular interpolation expects expressions which have access only to scope properties. Therefore, access to `Date` is not available in the expression. Instead, you can create a scope function which returns a date when passed in `year`, `month`, and `day` values

```
$scope.getDate = function(year, month, day){
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}
```

to use like this:

```
{{getDate(year, month, day) | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dznsfxsB7bKbAGmBS1uI?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, this answer does work but it calls getDate before year, month date are initialized. I still think this is the best answer.